# Can't send invoice date or PO number on invoice to QB

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

I have a working QBXML interface but I can't seem to add a couple of
data items to an invoice upload (to QB).  I am trying to add the
Invoice Date and P.O. Number.

The error QB is returning is:

> QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.

In an effort to make sure I am using
the correct XML format I did a transfer in the opposite directions
(from QB) in order to see what it is sending.

When sending an invoice to QB I have added the two following XML
elements (which cause the problem):

```
<TxnDate>2013-04-02</TxnDate>
```

and

```
<PONumber>ABC123</PONumber>
```

Either or both create the error.  If I omit both it works.

For example, the following works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><?qbxml version="10.0"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "stopOnError"><InvoiceAddRq requestID = "1"><InvoiceAdd><CustomerRef><ListID>800000D1-1371755142</ListID></CustomerRef><RefNumber>0071010001P</RefNumber><Memo></Memo><InvoiceLineAdd><ItemRef><ListID>80000001-1288815007</ListID></ItemRef><Desc>Software License Fee as per 6/19/07 Licensing Agreement</Desc><Quantity>1.00</Quantity><Rate>4000.0000</Rate></InvoiceLineAdd><InvoiceLineAdd><ItemRef><ListID>80000001-1288815007</ListID></ItemRef><Desc>Consulting hours as per 7/16/07 Large Contract for Consulting Services</Desc><Quantity>50.00</Quantity><Rate>100.0000</Rate></InvoiceLineAdd></InvoiceAdd></InvoiceAddRq> </QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>
```

but the following doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><?qbxml version="10.0"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "stopOnError"><InvoiceAddRq requestID = "1"><InvoiceAdd><CustomerRef><ListID>800000D1-1371755142</ListID></CustomerRef><RefNumber>0071010001P</RefNumber><Memo></Memo><TxnDate>2013-04-02</TxnDate><InvoiceLineAdd><ItemRef><ListID>80000001-1288815007</ListID></ItemRef><Desc>Software License Fee as per 6/19/07 Licensing Agreement</Desc><Quantity>1.00</Quantity><Rate>4000.0000</Rate></InvoiceLineAdd><InvoiceLineAdd><ItemRef><ListID>80000001-1288815007</ListID></ItemRef><Desc>Consulting hours as per 7/16/07 Large Contract for Consulting Services</Desc><Quantity>50.00</Quantity><Rate>100.0000</Rate></InvoiceLineAdd></InvoiceAdd></InvoiceAddRq> </QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>
```

and the following doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><?qbxml version="10.0"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "stopOnError"><InvoiceAddRq requestID = "1"><InvoiceAdd><CustomerRef><ListID>800000D1-1371755142</ListID></CustomerRef><RefNumber>0071010001P</RefNumber><Memo></Memo><PONumber >ABC123</PONumber><InvoiceLineAdd><ItemRef><ListID>80000001-1288815007</ListID></ItemRef><Desc>Software License Fee as per 6/19/07 Licensing Agreement</Desc><Quantity>1.00</Quantity><Rate>4000.0000</Rate></InvoiceLineAdd><InvoiceLineAdd><ItemRef><ListID>80000001-1288815007</ListID></ItemRef><Desc>Consulting hours as per 7/16/07 Large Contract for Consulting Services</Desc><Quantity>50.00</Quantity><Rate>100.0000</Rate></InvoiceLineAdd></InvoiceAdd></InvoiceAddRq> </QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>
```

I have spend at least 30 hours on this.  I am at a total loss of more ideas.  Any help would be appreciated.

Blake McBride

Answer (score 3):

The order of the tags you submit *is important*.

That means that if the QuickBooks OSR tells you that the correct order of tags is:

- TxnDate
- RefNumber
- PONumber
- Memo

Then you *must* send the tags in that order. Any other order will not work.

Your examples have tags in this order: (Memo before TxnDate)

- RefNumber
- Memo
- TxnDate

And this order: (Memo before PONumber)

- RefNumber
- Memo
- PONumber

Neither of which is correct.

If you re-order your tags, it will work.

Relevant [QuickBooks development FAQ entry](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbxml_questions#what_does_0x80040400_quickbooks_found_an_error_when_parsing_the_provided_xml_text_stream_mean) over here. Also, make sure you check out the XML Validator tool included with the QuickBooks SDK (it will tell you if your tags are out of order).

The [QuickBooks OSR](https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html) will show you the correct tag order.

Comment: yeah... really?.. order matters, eh? 3 hours wasted. Thanks for the post anyway - but please, PLEASE put this information in BOLD on every page of your wiki/FAQ/whatever you have there. It's SO uncommon, and the error from SDKTest.exe is so unclear that it's not even funny.

Comment: Since the vast majority of our wiki isn't about qbXML, I'm not sure that would be appropriate. You might consider sending something to Intuit though if it bothers you that much - I agree that they should document it a bit better. QuickBooks is notorious for returning error messages that are a bit confusing to figure out if you're not familiar with the platform.